# Improve interview skills before interviewing with good company?

Tags: interviewing

Is it bad idea to interview with dream companies if your interview skills is not up to snuff?  Say you bomb the interview will they put you on a do not hire list so it is impossible to apply again or better to brush up on interviewing before interviewing at dream companies?

For the record I suck at interviews and frequently do bad in them.

Comment: Which country are you in ? and which industry ?  For example, in the US and in the computer software industry, usually, if you fail an interview at a company, the earliest that company will interview you again is 6 months later. But, it could be a year or longer before they interview you again. It depends on the job market, and how many good job applicants the companies have to interview.

Comment: Most "dream" companies will ask that you wait at least one year before you reapply (some 6 months). What kind of companies are you applying to? To what type of position are you applying for? There are many ways to practice and simulate interviews. But without knowing what kind of job you're looking for, it's difficult to give you good advice.

Comment: Obviously if your interview skills are poor, then it would be better to get some practice in. However unless your interview really is reprehensibly bad, then most companies won't hold a previous failure against you. Many companies run beauty contests involving considerable numbers of candidates, where each round of recruitment generates large numbers of rejects on fairly spurious reasons, so you likely won't stand out.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it bad idea to interview with dream companies if your interview skills is not up to snuff?

Yes, you're not maximising your chances of getting the job.

The easiest way to get jobs with poor interviewing skills is to do so through your network.